# Qualified Random Selection in MS Access using a Loop?

Tags: random, selection, ms-access-2010

I am using Windows 7, Access 2010

I have a database that I need to return a random set of records from.  The tables are relational.

I have the following tables:

- Competencies
- Elements
- Sections
- Examples

I created a query with an expression that numbered the records and I was able to randomly select x number of records.

The issue is:
Within the Elements, I need to RANDOMLY select x number of Sections within EACH element.  So with my current set up I get x number of sections but it does not include at least one section from each Element.  I would like to return say 25% of sections from each element.

i.e.
Element:  7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4
Section: 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3: 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.3.3 etc

My query is returning randomly but not from EACH element.  So I might have all from element 7.1, 1 from 7.2 and nothing from 7.3 or 7.4.

Is there a way to do this?  I think I might need a loop but I am completely unfamiliar with that so I'd need help with the appropriate VBA code to get it to work.

I have googled everything I can think of and I'm not getting anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a "select n from group" type of query, but you will need a unique ID:

```
SELECT
  t.ID, 
  t.Element, 
  t.Section
FROM Elements AS t
WHERE t.ID In (
     SELECT Top 2 ID 
     FROM Elements q 
     WHERE q.Element=t.Element 
     ORDER BY Rnd([id])*1000)
```

I have been over this a number of times and I reckon you are going to have to add a field for your random sort, then update the field before you run the query. This will update a field called RandomNumber in [Competency Elements]

```
 UPDATE [Competency Elements] 
 SET [Competency Elements].RandomNumber = Rnd([element id])*1000;
```

Then the percentage select, I think it has to be greater than 33 for this particular data set:

```
SELECT Val([comp section number]) AS [Sect No],
       s.[section description],
       e.[element number],
       e.[element description],
       Rnd(e.[element id])        AS Expr1,
       s.[section id],
       e.[element id],
       x.example,
       s.[competency id],
       c.[comp number],
       c.[competency category]
FROM   competencies AS c
       INNER JOIN (([competency sections] AS s
                    INNER JOIN [competency elements] AS e
                            ON s.[section id] = e.[section id])
                   INNER JOIN examples AS x
                           ON e.[element id] = x.[element id])
               ON c.[competency id] = s.[competency id]
WHERE  (( ( e.[element id] ) IN (SELECT TOP 35 PERCENT [element id]
                                 FROM   [competency elements] q
                                 WHERE  q.[section id] = e.[section id]
                                 ORDER  BY randomnumber) ))
ORDER  BY Val([comp section number]);
```

There are a number of issues around getting a random selection from a group.

Comment: I have a primary key. If I write that as is, the "t" means table? Do I put that code in my query?  What does the "*1000" do?  Thank you so much!

Comment: I also need to feed these results into a report that I already have set up.  I am assuming this is a query return but I am not sure. I have never written a code into Access before.

Comment: `Elements As t` means an alias (assign the name t to this table). You need it so that you can refer to Elements again in the inner SQL `FROM Elements q`, which ca be written `FROM Elements AS q`. *1000 because Rnd returns a small decimal, so multiplying up.

Comment: Yes, this is a query. If the names are right `Elements, ID, Section` etc, you can just paste into SQL view of the query design window.

Comment: I am not sure what ID is? The other names are correct.  I had a syntax error when I tried it.

Comment: ID is the name of your primary key.

Comment: When I run it, a window pops up asking me to enter the parameter value and says it may be to complex to be evaluated.  Sorry, I can't figure this out.

Comment: My tables are actually competency element, competency section so I made these changes:  SELECT t.[element ID], t.[Competency Elements], t.[Competency Sections] FROM [Competency Elements] AS t WHERE t.[element ID] In ( SELECT Top 2 [element ID] FROM [Competency Elements] q WHERE q.Element=t.Element ORDER BY Rnd([id])*1000);

Comment: Enter Parameters: q.Elements, t.Elements, t.Sections         What is q?  I wish I could post an image of my query but it will not let me.

Comment: If you will look above, I posted an example using your field names.

Comment: I did and I used it and I get that enter parameters message when I run it.

Comment: element id is the primary key in the elements table.  Is that the problem?  After I enter through the parameter messages it returns an empty query with columns element id, sections, elements.

Comment: Sorry, but you could not get an error message asking you for elements as a parameter using the second example above. Please post the sql from the query you used. As I said above, q is just another name for the same table -- it is a nickname, you need it so you can refer to the same table twice.

Comment: It is asking me for:  q.competency elements, t.competency elements, t.competency sections

Comment: Notice that in my example there are square brackets  q.[competency elements] Do you have square brackets around the names when there are spaces? What are the field names in your table? Why not post your sql?

Comment: SELECT t.[element ID], t.[Competency Elements] AS Expr1, t.[Competency Sections] AS Expr2
FROM [Competency Elements] AS t
WHERE (((t.[element ID]) In (SELECT Top 2 [element ID] 
   FROM [Competency Elements] q 
   WHERE q.[Competency Elements]=t.[Competency Elements] 
ORDER BY Rnd([element id])*1000)));

Comment: Above is what I have.  Copied it exact from the code above.  Once I RAN it the AS Expr1, etc was added.  I didn't put that in there.  I apologize, I normally pick up on things quickly but when it comes to code I feel totally lost and it's so frustrating!

Comment: See this  t.[Competency Elements] AS Expr1, t.[Competency Sections] AS Expr2? This means that you do not have fields called Competency Elements or Competency Sections. What are the field names in your table?

Comment: Do not apologise, you will get there soon enough :)

Comment: You have no idea how frustrated I am!  I feel like you can't teach an old dog new tricks!  I see.  I thought those were TABLE names and in that case it would be correct, the ID's in my table are different.  Just one second.

Comment: Frustrated that I cannot attache a picture of my tables.

Comment: So to know what I am trying to ask using the code, I need the field names in more than one table right?  Do they all have to be the primary keys?  Also FROM I think would be the table name, select is the field names, correct?  AS and WHERE I am not sure of.

Comment: I don't have either of those.  Is there an e-mail or something that I could send it to you?

Comment: Sent you the database design.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your persistence with helping me!  It works perfectly!  Merry Christmas.  :)